# SSRS Drill down report not using same credentials as parent report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, drilldown, drillthrough

I have created a drill down SSRS report where I have put text boxes and 5 sub reports and one as main report.For main report datasource I have selected "Display the following text to prompt user for a user name and password:" and have checked "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source" box. But the problem is I have to login every time I click on each tab and go to next sub report. Please let me know if anyone has a solution.

Comment: Can you try to add more detail to your question, such as pictures of the subreports, so we can see what your setup looks like? Screenshots of the datasources of each report may help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/82b7aea6-2a47-4ca2-9234-d4a8f464f602/avoid-prompt-for-credentials-on-subreports?forum=sqlreportingservices), you need to make sure the datasource name is exactly the same for all subreports. Then it will only prompt for the main report.

Comment: I have set all the subreports with same datasets and security settings as parent report. Yet it is not working.